# How to require a react component from a file containing multiple components?

Tags: testing, reactjs, export

I have the following

```
 var comp1 = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
            return (
            <div>
            <div class="content">
            <p> information here ..</p>
            </div>
            </div>
            );
        }
    });

    var comp2 = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
            return (
            <div>
            <div className="content">
            <p>information here</p>
            </div>
            </div>
            )
        }
    });
```

How do I require comp1 in another test file

I added module.exports at the end of the file and required as

```
var myComponents = require('../js/components/App.js').comp1
```

But get the following error

```
  - TypeError: Cannot read property 'exports' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
module.exports.comp1 = comp1;
module.exports.comp2 = comp2;
```

or alternativeley:

```
module.exports = {comp1: comp1, comp2: comp2};
```

Then require:

```
var Components = require('./path_to_file');
var comp1 = Components.comp1;
var comp2 = Components.comp2;
```

Comment: Can you give more info?  How you do the export, where you get the error, etc.